# Trying to hash a username and store it in DB using hashlib and flask

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, hashlib

I am trying to hash a username, using hashlib, that I am getting from a form before committing it to a DB.

Code:

```
@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST']) #enabling POST request method on this page
def signup(): #create function to handle route
    if request.method == 'POST': #if POSTING to server get data from form
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        
        #checks database for already existing account name and email
        account = Account.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if account:
            flash('User already exists', category='error')
        emailCheck = Account.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if emailCheck:
            flash('User already exists', category='error')

        #perform some data checks
        if len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email is too short', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords do not match', category='error')
        elif len(username) < 5:
            flash('Username too short', category='error')
        else:
            #hash the username
            username = hashlib.sha256(username.encode('utf-8'))
            #create new user using User schema
            new_account = Account(email=email, username=username, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256')) #user name and password are created and hashed before being stored.
            db.session.add(new_account)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_account, remember=True)
            flash('Account Created', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.getuserinfo'))

    return render_template("signup.html", user=current_user)
```

I am able to get the username and commit without hashing it. However once I use this line:

```
username = hashlib.sha256(username.encode('utf-8'))
```

It gives me the error: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type. Hashing and storing a value should be relatively easy so I am really not sure where I am going wrong. I followed the documentation on hashlib as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: After playing around with it for a bit I managed to come up with a different error. I changed my hashing code to look like this:

```
hashedusername = hashlib.sha256(str('username'))
            #create new user using User schema
            new_account = Account(email=email, username=hashedusername, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/nicholas/Documents/CY 324 Web App/website/auth.py", line 71, in signup
    hashedusername = hashlib.sha256(str('username'))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: I think you should use `hashlib.sha256(username.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`. The function returns a HASH object from which the digest should be extracted.

Comment: See comment above: Exactly I did the same to generate "a string" that your binding will most probably will check for.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying the `hexdigest()` is the hashed value as a string? So the `hashlib.sha256()` returns a hash object which is not a string? Your solution worked, so thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Nicholas Your database expects a string. `hashlib.sha256` returns a HASH object. The function `hexdigest` queries the digest as a bytes object and converts it into a hex string.